# Burial of Children

Tags: minhag, funeral-burial-levaya, minor-katan-child

Why is it customary to bury children on the outskirts or in a separate section of the cemetery?

Comment: It is?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ברוב בתי העלמין בישראל מקצים חלקת קבורה המיועדת לקבורת ילדים, חלקות אלו הינן חלקות נפרדות מבית העלמין כיוון שהקונסטרוקציה של הקברים הינם קטנות יותר משאר החלקות בבתי העלמין המיועדות לנפטרים בוגרים יותר.
A little pragmatic but it might be the Answer
[From Here](http://www.memorials.co.il/2010/02/%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C/)

Comment: Thanks for the source. It may be true but I would like to see an answer (if there is) from more of a Torah source. I would even be comfortable with the same answer if it came from a Chevrah Kadisha source. The problem with the answer you brought is that it assumes that when we used to bury in family (man-made) caves (as in the time of the Gemarah, the children were buried alongside the adults. Is that true or not?